# "onbeforeunload" not firing on unload

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

I stuck this in a .js file...

```
window.onbeforeunload = alert('onbeforeunload');
```

But it fires when the page is loaded, not when it is unloaded.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it... try this instead:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){alert('onbeforeunload')};
```

Comment: That didn't work... now nothing happens... even the page loading alert has stopped

Comment: scratch that... it is only not working in Opera browser. I just tried firefox and it works.

Comment: hmmm... you don't need the function... it was only not working because of Opera

Answer (score 10):

change this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = alert('onbeforeunload');
```

to this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {alert('onbeforeunload');}
```

`onbeforeunload` takes a function reference which it will fire on before unload.  You are technically assigning the return value of a function as the `alert` is firing when it is encountered on the page.

Comment: That didn't work... now nothing happens... even the page loading alert has stopped

Comment: scratch that... it is only not working in Opera browser. I just tried firefox and it works.

Comment: hmmm... you don't need the function... it was only not working because of Opera